# Could not execute statement; for uniqueness DataIntegrityViolationException :

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

The exact error:

```
"DataIntegrityViolationException : could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UCIDXNUFQCFS2J6QMVYBIXJFNORH8C]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement (Duplicate entry 'QQAB3GY' for key 'UCIDXNUFQCFS2J6QMVYBIXJFNORH8C')
```

My class has `id` and `non-id` field which is `alphanumeric` and has 5 characters and unique and 2 characters prefix:

```
public class Holiday {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Size(min = 7, max = 7)
    private String reference;

}
```

i am setting this `code` field in another service:

```
@Transactional(isolation = SERIALIZABLE)
@Override
public String generateReference(String productCode) {

    ReferenceGenerator referenceGenerator = referenceGeneratorRepository.findByMnemonic(productCode);

    if (referenceGenerator != null) {
        referenceGenerator.setValue(incrementReference(referenceGenerator.getValue()));
        referenceGeneratorRepository.save(referenceGenerator);
    } else {
        referenceGenerator = referenceGeneratorRepository.save(new ReferenceGenerator(PREAPP, START_VALUE_FOR_REFERENCE_CODE));
    }

    return PREFIX_OF_REFERENCE_CODE + referenceGenerator.getValue();
}
```

I set like this:

```
private final ReferenceGeneratorService referenceGeneratorService;
Holiday holiday = new Holiday();
holiday.setReference(referenceGeneratorService.generateReference(PREAPP));
```

The db is `mysql` and we use `spring boot.`

When i send multiple requests at same time, for example from `swagger`, it can give

> **DataIntegrityViolationException** **, the reference is already used**

I tried lots of things.

I am open to any suggestions. The purpose is the field must be unique and alphanumeric.

I tried that for example:

[String increment for alphanumeric field is for JPA not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257057/string-increment-for-alphanumeric-field-is-for-jpa-not-working/53259441#53259441)

QQ is `prefix`

Comment: The error suggests that the key generated or the unique column had a duplicate entry, did you try to debug and check if that is the case.

Comment: @Anas i tried to send multiple requests to save, so because of this it happens.If i debug, i cant do it so fast. I send 10 15 requests in 10 seconds to save. So it cant lock database for it probably.

Comment: Assuming if you debug the 10 15 request and the issue doesn't arise, then it means its a concurrency issue and since spring boot works on threads for each request, can you try using any concurrent object? For example ConcurrentHashMap