# i am unable access session.connection(); method for my custom id generator in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```java
package com.ashokit.generators;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

public class OrderIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    
      @Override
        public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String prefix = "OD";
          String suffix = "";
          try {
                       session.connection();
              
          }catch(Exception e){
              
          }
            return null;
        }   

}
```

Comment: What means "unable", can you elaborate on what the output (error) was? You may also have a look on the tutorial commented to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736782/how-to-implement-identifiergenerator-with-prefix-and-separate-sequence-for-each).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).